# wanting to fetch firestore like realTimeDatabase

Tags: swift, algorithm, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

is there any way in Firestore to get List of Data in single array ,, for example ..in  RealTimeDatabase we get Data array by calling single value instead of using ForEachLoop...for Example in realtimeDatabase we get value by

```
var PersonObjArrays  : [Person] = [ ] () 

  Database.database().
  reference.child("personFullname").observe( .childAdded.  
   , with : { (snapshot) in 

 let snapShotValue = snapshot.value

 let firstname = snapShotValue["firstname"] as! String
 let lastname = snapShotValue["lastname"] as! String

 let personObj = Person( firstname ,lastname)

 self.messageArray.append(personObj)
```

but in Firestore we have to used ForLoop  .....For Example in Firestore we used

```
 FireStore.firestore()
  .collection("personFullname").
   getDocuments { (snapshot , error ) in 

          for document in snaphot.document {      

                 let data = document.data( )
                 let firstName = data["firstname"] as! String
                 let lastnamNname = data["lastname"] as! String

                let personObj2 = Person( firstName , lastName)
               self.messageArray.append(personObj2)
 }
```

So is there any way to get Data of Firestore as whole ObjectArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database always returns a `DataSnapshot`. Even when the results are guaranteed to be a list, you get back a `DataSnapshot`, where each child node is an element from that list.

Cloud Firestore returns a different type for a singular results vs a list of results. For a single result Firestore returns a `DocumentSnapshot` or a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, which allows you to get the values (and metadata) of a single document. For a query or collection, Firestore returns a `QuerySnapshot`, which contains a *list* of `DocumentSnapshot`/`QueryDocumentSnapshot` objects.

There is no way to request an equivalent to `.childAdded` from Cloud Firestore. This was an intentional change by the API designers, as many developers were confusing the two roles that a `DataSnapshot` might have in results there.

In RTDB terms, Firestore always fires a `.value` event, and you'll have to loop over the results. If you loop over [`QuerySnapshot.docChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#doc-changes) only check for `type` = `added` in [`QueryDocumentSnapshot.status`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange.html#type) you have the equivalent of the Realtime Database's `.childAdded`.

---

So the equivalent to your `.childAdded` listener would be something like:

```
FireStore.firestore()
  .collection("personFullname")
  .getDocuments { (snapshot , error ) in 
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) {
            let data = diff.document.data( )
            let firstName = data["firstname"] as! String
            let lastnamNname = data["lastname"] as! String

            let personObj2 = Person( firstName , lastName)
            self.messageArray.append(personObj2)
        }
    }
  })
```

This is all based on [this section in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), so I highly recommend studying that.

Comment: Added an example. But I also highly recommend you study the documentation, and take the Firestore codelab for iOS developers here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-ios/